# Devise and OmniAuth: Initialize Request Sent Twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise

I am using Devise and OmniAuth and have followed this tutorial: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Everything works fine, but my app sends a request to Facebook twice whenever the user clicks on:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

I do not even have an omniauth.rb file.

Here is what I see in the console:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-19 21:04:03 -0400 I, [2014-08-19T21:04:03.832699 #54281]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-19 21:04:03 -0400 I, [2014-08-19T21:04:03.854510 #54281]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? How can I prevent two requests from being sent?

Comment: did you found solution?